# Shrimp Breeding

Tags: aquarium, breeding

I just picked up some Jade Shrimp (pretty cool, bred to be green, not dyed) and the employee (whom I'm quite acquainted with) threw in a pregnant one! Woohoo, right?

Anyway, the question is, she is nesting and looking ready to pop...once she lays the eggs, do they need to be inseminated or are they already and she just takes care of them until hatch?

No fish in the tank, just shrimp and snails, so it should be a nice little crop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some text from the wikipedia page of Neocaridina Davidi which is your shrimp. (bold format from me)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neocaridina_davidi

About breeding:

> N. davidi shrimp reach sexual maturity when they are around 4–6 months
>   old. Breeding only requires a sexed pair of shrimp, stable water
>   parameters, and a food source.[10] Eggs may be observed developing in
>   the female's ovaries as a green or yellow triangular "saddle" marking
>   on her back. When she is ready to lay the eggs, which occurs after
>   molting, she releases pheromones into the water to signal her
>   availability to males. The male shrimp in the tank will often become
>   agitated, swimming very actively about as they search for the source
>   of the pheromones. **After a brief mating process, during which the male
>   deposits sperm onto the female's body, the female lays her eggs and
>   affixes them to her swimmerettes. The eggs are not fertilized within
>   the female; they are fertilized as they pass from the ovaries to the
>   outside of the body. Therefore, it is certain that any shrimp carrying
>   eggs has mated.** A female carrying eggs under her abdomen is said to be
>   "berried".[citation needed]
>
> Some report that young female shrimp carrying their first clutch of
>   eggs tend to drop some or all of the eggs, possibly due to
>   inexperience or small size.[11] If a berried shrimp is stressed by
>   predators or poor water conditions she may also abandon the eggs.[12]

So if the eggs are already under her "tail", fertilization already happened. The eggs still take some time to hatch. Be aware that a female shrimp that feels scared, vulnerable or inexperienced might drop the eggs. Being transported from petshop to home and entering a new aquarium can be stressful for shrimps and it's very possible that those first eggs can be abandonned. (it happened like this for me in the past) Bright lights, fast movements and loud sounds can also scare shrimps.

Many things matter with shrimp, safety and lots of cover and warmer water will help with breeding. Also plants and food and clean water. I advise you to google as much as you can about them. :)

PS: never put aquarium salt or anything containing copper (including medication or snail killers) in the shrimp tank

Hope that answered your question

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice as well as funding the wiki entry. I didn't know their real name so I wasn't sure how to look them up.. so I can see the eggs inside of her abdomen area, they aren't "outside, under he tail.." so am I understanding it correctly that they aren't yet fertilized? Also,  they've got a great aquarium, very heavily planted, lots of places to hide and it is only shrimp and smails, so there is not any predators. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you could get a good quality photo of the situation.. ? Otherwise it's hard to tell for me.  Egg "laying" and mating will occur after molting of the mother. Sounds like your tank is a good environment so just keep the water extra clean, give enough food, make sure there's a sponge on your filter intake so it doesnt suck up the shrimps.

I also once observed anxiously my pregnant females but in vain, I think she lost them. When you will see the little babies swimming you will know for sure! :p

Comment: You could also look up pictures on google images for "berried" neocaridina (any color) and compare with yours. The saddle is in the back, the fertilized eggs (berried) are under abdomen. Red Cherry Shrimp is one of the more common colorations for this animal.

Comment: Oh good, tip, I have an overflow filter and they could easily accidentally wander into the filter, the current isn't strong but the slits where the water flows could easily be mistaken by a baby shrimp. And, ok, so it does sound like she is indeed fully pregnant.